# Выделение из массива двух массивов, сумма элементов которых равна

Tags: алгоритм

Суть задачи:
В спортивном зале города N появилась штанга и набор блинов с различными массами. Для занятия спортом необходимо распределить блины по двум концам штанги таким образом, чтобы суммарный вес по оба конца штанги был одинаковый. Рассчитайте максимальный вес, который смогут поднимать спортсмены при заданном наборе блинов (с допущением, что гриф штанги невесомый).
Пример:

> На входе: [1,2,3,6] На выходе: 12 Пояснение: можно нацепить блины {1,2,3} с одной стороны и блин {6} с другой, что в сумме даст 12.
>
> На входе: [1,2,3,4,5,6] На выходе: 20 Пояснение: можно нацепить блины {2,3,5} с одной стороны и блины {4,6} с другой, что в сумме даст 20. Оставшийся блин {1} не может быть нацеплен ни с одной из сторон без потери равновесия.
>
> На входе: [1,2] На выходе: 0 Пояснение: данный набор блинов невозможно нацепить без потери равновесия.

Пока нашел такую последовательность действий:

- Посчитать сумму всех элементов. Если сумма не четная, то находим минимальный элемент массива, который при вычете даст четную сумму. Убираем его.
- Если сумма четная, то используя жадный алгоритм разбиваем массив на два подмассива с одинаковой или близкой к одинаковой сумме.
- Если суммы подмассивов оказались не равны, то вычитаем из массива следующий элемент, который в результате разности даст четную сумму.

Например:

- на входе [4, 3, 3, 3, 3] сумма 16.
- в результате вышеописанного алгоритма, на два равных по сумме массива не делится.
- находим элемент массива, который в разности даст четную сумму - 4 (16-4 = 12)
- прогоняем алгоритм для массива [3, 3, 3, 3], который находит решение.

Мне кажется, что описанный алгоритм не совершенен и не работает для всех случаев. Может быть есть готовый алгорит для такой задачи?